# different confirmation boxes on firefox when running remotewebdriver tests

Tags: firefox, testing

When testing my webapp manually I get a confirm box: [http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1342388/syneto/good_conf_box_1.png http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1342388/syneto/good_conf_box_1.png](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1342388/syneto/good_conf_box_1.png), the browser renders it with an overlay, but when run with remotewebdriver the overlay is not present and the confirm is in a window [http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1342388/syneto/bad_conf_box_1.png http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1342388/syneto/bad_conf_box_1.png](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1342388/syneto/bad_conf_box_1.png), any idea why is this happening?

Same browser, FF4.
The remotewebdriver sends an instantiated FirefoxProfile without modifications that adds this [user.js](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1342388/syneto/user.js) to the Firefox Profile.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this line to the **bottom** of the user.js profile to force modal prompts:

```
user_pref("prompts.tab_modal.enabled", true);
```

One of the lines in `user.js` is likely resetting the default behaviour for Firefox 4 prompts, so adding that line at the end of `user.js` should override the reset and force the new prompt style.

Answer (score 0):

WebDriver deliberately sets prompts.tab_modal.enabled to false to be able to deal with alerts across Firefox versions. You can't override the setting at the moment.